# How can I filter() within a function() in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that runs a linear regression to a subset of my data. I want to run two separate regressions for each id. These regressions should be used to add a new column that gives the residuals for each model. The variable e_hat is the desired outcome I want to create.

```
#create sample data
x <- rnorm(10,10,1)
id <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1")
e <- rnorm(10,0,1)
data <- data.frame(cbind(id,x,e))
data$y <- 27+1.2*as.numeric(data$x)+as.numeric(data$e)
x <- rnorm(10,10,3)
id <- c("2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2")
e <- rnorm(10,0,2)
data2 <- data.frame(cbind(id,x,e))
data2$y <- 10+1.6*as.numeric(data$x)+as.numeric(data$e)
data <- rbind(data, data2)

#my code
unex_changes <- function(x, y, z){
  model <- lm(as.numeric(y)~as.numeric(x), data=filter(data, id == z))
  data$y - predict(model)
}
data <- mutate(data,e_hat = unex_changes( x, y, id))
```

However, the filtering approach I used does not work properly because the regression parameters are estimated based on the entire dataset. Does someone has another solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that in `id == z`, `z` contains both the ids 1 and 2. So the `data=filter(data, id == z)` is not working, and the filtered table is the same as before.
Let me know whether this works for you:

```
#my code
unex_changes <- function(x, y, z){
  predictions <- c()
  for (i in unique(z)){
    model <- lm(as.numeric(y)~as.numeric(x), data=filter(data, id == i))
    predictions <- c(predictions, filter(data, id == i)$y - predict(model))
  }
  return(predictions)
}
data <- mutate(data,e_hat = unex_changes( x, y, id))
data
```